# Regular expression for currency formate

Tags: javascript, regex

```
var s = 5.3756875;
s.toString().replace(/[^0-9.]/g, '').replace(/\B(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
```

My output for decimal is 22.4,445 i need 22.4445

Answer (score 0):

Using Regular Expressions you have to exclude digits after decimal point:

```js
var number = 52648935.159698;
console.log(
    number.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))|(\.\d+)$/g,
        function($0, $1) { return $1 ? $1 : ','; }
    )
);
```